# eth0 not detected in 6.6 based OS

Tags: centos

[image]

After installation this centos based os setup netowrk failed because eth0 is not found

It recognizes eth1

Can Inuse that one? If so how?

Or how can I fix this? It is an HP notebook with intel chipset and realtek ethernet adapter.

Comment: How many Ethernet ports do you have on this laptop? Is eth0 renamed to eth1?

Comment: Just one ethernet port @epik - no odea if it was renamed (not that I am aware of) before it finctionee as a windows 8 laptop..

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

Find where it says `NAME="eth1"` and change to `NAME="eth0"`

Then go to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` and rename `ifcfg-eth1` to `ifcfg-eth0`

then reboot, or `sudo service network restart`

**[Tutorial here](http://minimallinux.blogspot.ca/2013/06/centos-6rhel-change-eth1-back-to-eth0.html)**